# How to implement Realtime push notification for my website?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, web, comet

I have a website which has two parts. The first part is used by `X` people and the second by `Y` people. The `X` people asks for help and the `Y` people instantly receiving the *SOS* resonds with an *ETA* of their arrival. I am using `PHP-MySQL` implementing the database and logging all the interactions of X and Y people. I know I can use Ajax for this purpose. Then Again I am not a big fan of Polling through `setInterval` method.

> Which is the best approach to push messages and show notificaions from
>   one page to another?

Comment: If you are using PHP, how does Node.js fit in?

Comment: PHP (or Node) + websocket html 5 = win

Comment: Definitely check out Firebase. It will change your life.

Comment: maybe it can help you: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world however if ditch out the php from the scenario come to be an option, try out all the nice stuff available for node servers.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do that, here are some:

- Try using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications)
- Watch [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzKNsX4zAPw) it has a very good and simple set of examples.

Comment: This YouTube video link is set to private for those that are reading this comment. Unsure if this is permanent.

Comment: It was not private at the time.